# Копирование памяти memcpy()

Tags: c++

Необходимо создать блок памяти, и по определенным смещениям в этой памяти записать данные. Для начала мне нужно скопировать в блок памяти *HANDLE* открытого устройства. Делаю вот так:

```
VOID WINAPI GetDeviceInfo(HANDLE hDevice)
{

    BYTE *rData = nullptr, *wrt = nullptr;

    rData = (BYTE*)malloc(0x90);
    if(rData)
    {
        ZeroMemory(rData, 0x90);

        wrt = rData;

        wrt += 0x8;

        memcpy(wrt, hDevice, sizeof(hDevice));

        free(rData);
    }
}
```

При отладке программа падает на строчке с `memcpy`, говорит, что я куда-то не туда залез.

Comment: Хм.. А что в этом вопросе с языком программирования? `nullptr` - это плюсы, причём очень даже современные, а неявный каст из HANDLE (которым является нечто unsigned) - это си без плюсов. Как это чудо компилируется? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy `HANDLE`, вероятно, объявлен как `typedef void *HANDLE;`, потому каста тут может не быть.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

В таком виде как у Вас, `memcpy(wrt, hDevice, sizeof(hDevice))` копирует не `hDevice`, а пытается скопировать память по указателю `hDevice`.

`hDevice` может, конечно же, на самом деле быть указателем, но может и не быть. Или быть, но указывать на область памяти, куда приложению доступа нет. В этом и причина падения. Хуже было бы, если бы он оказался валидным указателем. Тогда падения бы не было, а просто по-тихому записывались бы неверные данные.

А чтобы записать значение самого `hDevice`, нужно при помощи `&` получить адрес в памяти, где хранится `hDevice`. Должно быть как-то так `memcpy(wrt, &hDevice, sizeof(hDevice))`.

Answer (score 2):

В функции `memcpy` первые два аргумента это УКАЗАТЕЛИ на приемник и источник, то есть вы при копировании вы пытаетесь скопировать из памяти по адресу `hDevice`; чтобы скопировать сам хендл исправьте второй аргумент на `&hDevice`.